# Unable to reproduce properly the copy of image from one canvas to other canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

Well my main motto is to transmit the image displayed(server) on canvas to client, so that it will display the same image in it's own canvas element.

But for now, what I do is, at the server side itself, I create another canavs in the same webpage,

My code is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_win");
var gl;
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas_win1");
var gl1;

try {
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {premultipliedAlpha: false}) || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{premultipliedAlpha: false});
} catch (e) {
}
if (!gl) {
    alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
}   

try {
    gl1 = canvas.getContext("webgl", {premultipliedAlpha: false}) || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{premultipliedAlpha: false});
} catch (e) {
}
if (!gl) {
    alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
}



var dataURLstring = canvas_win.toDataURL();
var ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');  
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_win1.width, canvas_win1.height);
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
};
img.src = dataURLstring;
```

So I am running WebGL based volume rendering, so for any gui operation on canvas_win generates a rendered image and displays on its own canvas. Now, this displayed image i need to copy to another canvas. 
I am trying to clear the prevous copied image into canvas_win1 and display the current image copied from canvas_win.

But I see some extra shading in the copied image. I do not know what is causing that. Herein, I have attached the snapshot of canvas. Left is the original. Rigt is the copied version.

[image: Displayed image on Canvas]

Another observation, sometimes the image displayed is perfectly but other time there is black shading added. I am testing it on Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 m (64-bit) and also tested on Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1

Any insights into this is useful.

Regards,
Prajwal

```js
/* 
 Copyright 2011 Vicomtech

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

// Volumerc.js

/*
GLobal variables
*/

/*
Zoom factor
*/
var zoom=2.0;

/*
*/
var drawVolume;

var time, end, start;
var count=0;
/*
Mouse Positions
*/
var mouseDown = false;
var lastMouseX = null;
var lastMouseY = null;
var mouseZoom = null;


/*
Matrix which rotates the cube
*/
var objectRotationMatrix = createRotationMatrix(90, [1, 0, 0]).x(createRotationMatrix(180, [0, 0, 1]));


/*
load_resource

get a document from a web direction
*/
function load_resource(url) {
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open('GET', url, false);
 req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
 req.send(null);

 if (req.status != 200) return '';
 return req.responseText;
}


/*
initShaders

function to get the shaders from an url and compile them
*/
function initShaders(gl, vertex_url, fragment_url)
{
 var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

 var src = load_resource(vertex_url);
 gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, src);
 gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
 {
  return null;
 }

 src = load_resource(fragment_url);

 gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, src);
 gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
 {
  return null;
 }

 var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();

 gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
 gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
 gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  alert("Linking " + vertex_url + "+"+ fragment_url + "\n ------------ \n" + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
 }

 gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

 shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

 shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

 shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
 shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");

 return shaderProgram
}


/*
cubeBuffer

Create a cube in webgl with color vertex for each axis
*/
function cubeBuffer(gl)
{
 var cube = new Object();
 cube.VertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexPositionBuffer);
 var vertices = [
  // Front face
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

  // Back face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

  // Top face
  0.0,  1.0, 0.0,
  0.0,  1.0, 1.0,
  1.0,  1.0, 1.0,
  1.0,  1.0, 0.0,

  // Bottom face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

  // Right face
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

  // Left face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
 ];
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 cube.VertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
 cube.VertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

 cube.VertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexColorBuffer);

 var colors = [
  // Front face
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,

  // Back face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

  // Top face
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

  // Bottom face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

  // Right face
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

  // Left face
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
 ];

 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 cube.VertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
 cube.VertexColorBuffer.numItems = 24;

 cube.VertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexIndexBuffer);
 var VertexIndices = [
 0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
 4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
 8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
 12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
 16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
 20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
 ]
 gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(VertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 cube.VertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
 cube.VertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;

 return cube;
}

/*
setMatrixUniforms
 
define the model matrix and projection matrix for the model
*/
function setMatrixUniforms(gl)
{
 gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, new Float32Array(pMatrix.flatten()));
 gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, new Float32Array(mvMatrix.flatten()));
}

/*
drawCube

render the cube
*/
function drawCube(gl,cube)
{
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

 perspective(45.0, 1.0, 0.1, 100.0);
 loadIdentity();

 mvTranslate([0.0, 0.0, -zoom])
 mvPushMatrix();
 multMatrix(objectRotationMatrix);
 mvTranslate([-0.5, -0.5, -0.5])
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexPositionBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cube.VertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexColorBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, cube.VertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.VertexIndexBuffer);
 setMatrixUniforms(gl);
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cube.VertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

 mvPopMatrix();
}

/*
initFBO

initializes the Frame Buffer Objects
*/
function initFBO(gl, width, height)
{
 var fbo = gl.createFramebuffer();
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);

 fbo.depthbuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
 gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER,fbo.depthbuffer);

 gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);

 gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, fbo.depthbuffer);

 fbo.tex = gl.createTexture();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbo.tex);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(width*height*4));

 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

 gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbo.tex, 0);

 switch(gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER))
 {
  case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
   //alert("Framebuffer OK");
  break;
  case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
   alert("Framebuffer incomplete attachment");
  break;
  case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
   alert("Framebuffer incomplete missing attachment");
  break;
  case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS:
   alert("Framebuffer incomplete dimensions");
  break;
  case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
   alert("Framebuffer unsuported");
  break;
 }
 return fbo
}

/*
handleLoadedTexture

Create a texture from an image
*/
function handleLoadedTexture(gl,image, texture)
{
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

/*
initTexture

read the textures from internet and set the callbacks for the texture creation
*/
function initTexture(gl, imgData, imgTF)
{
 gl.tf_tex = gl.createTexture();
 gl.tf_img = new Image();
 gl.tf_img.onload = function()
 {
  handleLoadedTexture(gl, gl.tf_img, gl.tf_tex);
 }
 gl.tf_img.src = imgTF;


 gl.vol_tex = gl.createTexture();
 gl.vol_img = new Image();
 gl.vol_img.onload = function()
 {
  handleLoadedTexture(gl,gl.vol_img,gl.vol_tex)
  setTimeout(drawVolume, 1);
 }
 gl.vol_img.src = imgData;
 //gl.vol_img.src = "./skull.png";
 //gl.vol_img.src = "./engine.png";
}

/*
main function
*/
function volumerc_main(rayfrag, imgData, imgTF)
{
 start = new Date().getTime();
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = start; 
 
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_win");
 var gl;
 var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas_win1");
 
 
 try {
  //gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {alpha: false}) || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{alpha: false});
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {premultipliedAlpha: false}) || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{premultipliedAlpha: false});
 } catch (e) {
 }
 if (!gl) {
  alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
 } 
 

 gl.shaderProgram_BackCoord = initShaders(gl,'./simple.vert','./simple.frag');
 gl.shaderProgram_RayCast = initShaders(gl,'./raycast.vert',rayfrag, imgData, imgTF);
 
 gl.fboBackCoord = initFBO(gl, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 initTexture(gl, imgData, imgTF);

 var cube = cubeBuffer(gl);

 canvas.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;
 document.onmouseup = handleMouseUp;
 document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

 
 

 drawVolume = function()
 {
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_win1.width, canvas_win1.height); 
  
  
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.fboBackCoord);
  gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_BackCoord;
  gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
  gl.clearDepth(-50.0);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
  drawCube(gl,cube);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_RayCast;
  gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
  gl.clearDepth(50.0);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.fboBackCoord.tex);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.vol_tex);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.tf_tex);

  gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uBackCoord"), 0);
  gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uVolData"), 1);
  gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uTransferFunction"), 2);

  //Set Texture
  drawCube(gl,cube);
  //console.log(gl.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 500)); 
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gl.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 500);
  //var img1 = new Image();
         
   
   
   var dataURLstring = canvas.toDataURL();
   
   var img = new Image;
   img.src = dataURLstring;
   img.onload = function(){
         ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
   };
   
   
   
  //img1.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gl;
  end = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = end-start; 
 }

 
 
 setTimeout(drawVolume, 15);
 
 
 
}

/*
MouseDown callback
*/
function handleMouseDown(event) {
 if (event.altKey){
  mouseZoom = true;
 }else {
  mouseDown = true;
  lastMouseX = event.clientX;
  lastMouseY = event.clientY;
 }
}
/*
MouseUp callback
*/
function handleMouseUp(event)
{
 mouseDown = false;
 mouseZoom = false;
}

/*
MouseMove callback
*/
function handleMouseMove(event)
{
 //count=count+1;
 //document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = count;
 
//alert('Execution time: ' + time);
 if (mouseDown) {
  var newX = event.clientX;
  var newY = event.clientY;

  var deltaX = newX - lastMouseX
  var newRotationMatrix = createRotationMatrix(deltaX / 10, [0, 1, 0]);

  var deltaY = newY - lastMouseY;
  newRotationMatrix = newRotationMatrix.x(createRotationMatrix(deltaY / 10, [1, 0, 0]));

  objectRotationMatrix = newRotationMatrix.x(objectRotationMatrix);

  lastMouseX = newX
  lastMouseY = newY;
  setTimeout(drawVolume, 1);

 } else if (mouseZoom) {
  var newX = event.clientX;
  var newY = event.clientY;

  var deltaX = newX - lastMouseX;
  var deltaY = newY - lastMouseY;

  zoom -= (deltaX+deltaY)/100,0;

  lastMouseX = newX;
  lastMouseY = newY;
  setTimeout(drawVolume, 1);

 }
 return;
}
```

```html
<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<TITLE>Real-Time Interactive Visualization of Volumetric Data with WebGL</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="sylvester.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="glUtils.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="glAux.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="volumerc.js"></SCRIPT>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40928041-1', 'volumerc.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<!-- 
</HEAD><BODY onload="volumerc_main('./raycast-color.frag','./aorta-low.jpg','./tfold.png');" bgcolor="white"> -->
<button type="button" onclick="volumerc_main('./raycast-color.frag','./aorta-high512.jpg','./tfold.png');">Load</button>
<CENTER>
<H1>Real-Time Interactive Visualization of Volumetric Data with WebGL</H1>

<canvas id="canvas_win" width="512" height="512" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>

<canvas id="canvas_win1" width="512" height="512" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>

</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: where is the code you use to create your WebGL context?

Answer (score 3):

Canvas2D canvases ALWAYS use *premultiplied alpha* and there's is generally no way to get invalid colors in the canvas2d API.

WebGL on the other hand it's very easy to make invalid colors because *it's up to you to make sure the values you write to the canvas are premultiplied by alpha* (or to set the canvas to premultipliedAlpha: false)

Here's an example. Run it.

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");

gl.clearColor(1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5);  // <=- INVALID COLOR
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

var img = new Image();
img.src = gl.canvas.toDataURL();
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
img, canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin 5px; 
  width: 150px;
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
```

Notice the image does not match the canvas. Why?

```
1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5
```

Was written to the canvas which is an invalid color because it's not premultiplied by alpha.

```
RGB *= A
```

If it was then the highest value (RED = 1.0) would now be 0.5

```
R * A = 1.0 * 0.5 = 0.5
```

So what happens when you call `toDataURL` is your values get *unpremultiplied by alpha* (because the values inside a png are unpremuliplied alpha. To unpremultiply we divide by alpha so

```
1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5
```

becomes

```
1 / 0.5, 0.8 / 0.5, 0.3 / 0.5, 0.5

=

2, 1.6, 0.6, 0.5
```

now clamp it to 1

```
1, 1, 0.6, 0.5
```

that's the color value put into the PNG.

The .PNG file then gets loaded into the browser. The browser then premultiplies the values (that's how it's able to correctly display transparent .PNG colors)

So

```
RGB *= A

1 * 0.5, 1 * 0.5, 0.6 * 0.5

0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5   <=- The color displayed for the image
```

If you want them to match you have several options

- Make sure you write premultiplied alpha into the canvas
- Turn off premultiplied alpha

  ```
  someCanvas.getContext("webgl", {premutlipliedAlpha: false});
  ```
- Turn off alpha

  ```
  someCanvas.getContext("webgl", {alpha: false});
  ```

As for serving the image why not just serve it as a .PNG or .JPG instead of a dataURL? It will be much smaller and compressed then.

```
    // Assuming node.js
    var base64PartOfDataURL = dataUrl.split(",")[0]
    var buf = new Buffer(base64PartOfDataURL, 'base64'); 

    // now serve buf as your result
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    res.write(buf);
    res.end();
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Under premultiplied alpha blending mode something like (1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0) just becomes additive blending. In fact, the alpha value is kinda like lerping between normal and additive blending: http://amindforeverprogramming.blogspot.ca/2013/07/why-alpha-premultiplied-colour-blending.html.

Comment: it becomes additive as far as it looks like in the canvas but if you call `toDataURL` and then try to display the resulting png you'll get 0,0,0,0 from 1,1,1,0

Comment: @gman Sorry for the late reply. Well I did change as you suggested setting premultiplied alpha to false. However the results aren't improved. Any hint on where I am going wrong. I have updated the code in main description.

Comment: You haven't made it clear how you created the 2 images. Is the second image just an image tag or is it being drawn in WebGL? If it's being drawn in WebGL **you need to show your drawing code**. Otherwise I have no idea. Maybe you mis-typed something? Try setting all the alpha to 1 with `gl.colorMask(false, false, false, true); gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` just **before** calling `canvas_win.toDataURL();`

Comment: @gman Herein I have attached the html page and volumerc.js script (in the original post). In volumerc.js script, function volumerc_main() the first and second canvas element are defined, 1st  image is webgl element whereas second image element is just canvas element. In draw volume function I copy the dataurl to img.src for 2nd canvas to display. Please have a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way is to use gl.readPixels(). The function reads the buffer of rendered data. So that can be read and copied to canvas. Here as observed the data mismatch doesn't happen. Below is the code:

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var imageData = canvas.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
imageData.data[i] = pixels[i];
};

canvas.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```